# WSDL, KSOAP2 Query

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2

Just want to ask if what does the 4th line do? or what is it for? Many thanks
I am building an application in android with phonegap

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://hello_webservice/";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.68:7001/HelloWebService/
HelloWSService?WSDL"; 
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "hello";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://hello_webservice/hello";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the SOAP action to be invoked, same at the namespace + the method name. Here is the doc: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528